# Technological guinea pig

Tags: visual, cipher

My little guinea pig "Aurora" is on holiday and it send me a message (yes is a hyper-technological guinea pig!!).
But unfortunately she has forgotten that I don't know the language of the guinea pigs :)
Who can help me to decipher its message?

```
ZG03BmV9ZGH7Zm0kBmD9AGf1CGD7Aw0kZmf3CGRjBmt9ZGD7BG0lBmRjCGZ7ZGR9AwfkZw05BmRmCGt7ZGD9ZGL7ZGH9ZGV7ZGL9ZGR=
```

1) 
[image]

2) 
[image]

3) 
[image]

4) 
[image]

5) 
[image]

6) 
[image]

7) 
[image]

8) 
[image]

9) 
[image]

10) 
[image]

11) 
[image]

12) 
[image]

13) 
[image]

14) 
[image]

15) 
[image]

16) 
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From left to right, top to bottom, the numbered images arranged in the following order create a QR code:

> 3 9 10 5  4 11 1 13  12 7 16 15  6 8 2 14

Here's the assembled QR code (pardon the border):

> [image: qr code]

The QR code, when put together, links here:

> http://q-r.to/bacySj 
>  Source image: 
> [image: aury.png]

So the decoded base64, thanks to Will, outlines the order shown above, which means that the final answer would be the image.

Answer (score 7):

## Partial answer

Your guinea pig has

> ROT13'd Base64
>  if we ROT13 it again, we get
>  `MT03OzI9MTU7Mz0xOzQ9NTs1PTQ7Nj0xMzs3PTEwOzg9MTQ7OT0yOzEwPTM7MTE9NjsxMj05OzEzPTg7MTQ9MTY7MTU9MTI7MTY9MTE=`
>
>  which decodes to:  `1=7;2=15;3=1;4=5;5=4;6=13;7=10;8=14;9=2;10=3;11=6;12=9;13=8;14=16;15=12;16=11`
>
>  this appears to describe how to reassemble the QR code, as Matt has already done