# Where is my technological guinea pig?

Tags: cipher

yesterday my guinea pig "***Aurora***" 
(that it's on holiday, see: [Technological guinea pig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31230/technological-guinea-pig))

invited me to join her ... but she is too "technological" for me ... and I can not decipher the invitation that contains the instructions to go to her !! :) 
Please, can someone help me??

```
SNRFK=T8
1_UJ=#5S9PU5
1_DOQE=#SU7D31
1_RCXVK=#FFW000
1_CSWT=#4472C4
2_OG=#8497P0
2_UOWH=#W4P084
2_IIGBK=#TWD966
2_LYWH=#7030R0
3_UP=#W00000
3_UCNN=#FZ0000
3_IWXHT=#ZWTW00
3_LEZK=#00P050
```

Hint:

> The colors are very very relevant...

[image]

Comment: geocaching - how?

Comment: ;) Yes it's a geocaching enigma!

Comment: I'm assuming it would help to know if the letters in the following locations are lowercase Ls or capital Is: O1, O2, S3, B19

Comment: @Matt If it's the same font as the column headers, capital i shows up with serifs, so they would be lowercase L's

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but some of the boxes are 'connected' together (no black grid lines separating them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> Somewhere in Hawaii...?

Explanation:

> First, we use a vigenere cipher on the text using the key 'Aurora'. This results in:
>
>   start=t8
>   1_up=#5b9bd5
>   1_down=#ed7d31
>   1_right=#ffc000
>   1_left=#4472c4
>   2_up=#8497b0
>   2_down=#f4b084
>   2_right=#ffd966
>   2_left=#7030a0
>   3_up=#c00000
>   3_down=#ff0000
>   3_right=#ffff00
>   3_left=#00b050
>
>   The left side denotes the number of steps in a direction, while the right is a legend for those steps.
>
>   Starting at cell T8, and continuing until I couldn't anymore. I ended up with:
>   **MjEuMzkzMDE0Oy0xNTcuODUzMzUxlA==**
>   The last = was bolded on the grid, so I think that indicated the end.
>
>   When base64decoded, I got **21.393014;-157.853351**, which on Google Maps, is somewhere in Hawaii.

Here are the colors for reference. I tried my best to match them up with the corresponding line.

> [image]

Comment: Very good job man!